# Getting child entity from parent entity in entity framework c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, model-view-controller

I have 1 to many relationship tables in SQL and I am using EF in MVC.
I would like to get all relational child from parent table. relationship is setup on DB level. PK to FK etc.

I want to delete entity with child (and child of child).

please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Consider showing what have you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

In the model configuration, you need to define child properties relations with WillCascadeOnDelete()

Plenty of examples are available on MSDN. For starters check [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#CascadeDelete)